# not equal to 0 checks for non null on pointer?

Tags: c++

Where p is the name of a pointer, does p != 0 return a bool that is true where p is null (not pointing at anything) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It specifically checks to see, as your title says, if the pointer is non-null, or is not the value `0x00000000`.  Your pointer might not actually be pointing at anything valid (e.g., could be a trashed pointer that just points to some random point in memory), but after that check you know it is not `NULL`.

EDIT :

Wording on the question got changed, but `p != 0` will return `true` if `p` is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  The C and C++ standards specify that the 0 pointer is not a valid memory location.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in C++, 0 is the value of the null pointer.

Comment: It's the null pointer constant, the actual null pointer could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Not pointing to anything means `a == NULL`.

However, on **any** modern computer/OS, `NULL` is reliably defined as `0`. Only if you are coding for embedded systems or compliant to very old standards, you should/have to use `NULL`. But the fact that you are using C++ rather than C already ensures that it is indeed 0.

Comment: `NULL` is defined to be (any constant expression the valuates to) zero. Any zero integral constant expression can be converted to a null pointer, which leaves the bit-pattern in the pointer in an implementation-defined state. But `NULL` must evaluate to zero, independent of OS.